# Sprites on CSS3D Renderer on mobile not looking to camera in ThreeJS?

Tags: canvas, three.js, mobile-devices

I want to sync two scenes with one control.

One scene is WebGL Renderer, second - CSS3D Renderer.

In desktop - everything is good, but on mobile devices (ex. Safari) canvas not working normally:

1. Canvas appears only after touchmove
2. Sprites not looking to camera
3. Sprites not rotating with WebGL scene by Orbit controls
   [image]

Sprites created with this code:

```
element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = `<div class="markern">
<span class="one"></span><span class="two"></span><span class="three"></span>
<a href="javascript:;" class="click"></a>
<div class="marker-text">
<h3 class="marker-title bebas">text</h3>
<p class="marker-excerpt">text</p>
</div>
</div>`;
element.className = 'marker';
divtext = new THREE.CSS3DSprite(element);
divtext.position.set(3200, 7200, 4000);
divtext.element.onclick = function() { page.popup(2); };
scene2.add(divtext);
```

DEMO: http://cavsys.ru/o-tehnologii/fizicheskij-uroven/